# Outer join - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have 2 tabels

```
Current Ecpense table
-----------------------

Month-----Type-------spent
Feb 12  Shopping   100 
Feb 12  Food       200
Jan 12  Shopping   456  
Jan 12  Food       452
Jan 12  Fuel       120
Jan 12  Rent       900

Previous Expense
-----------------------
Type------ spent 
Shopping   100
Food       100
Fuel       100
Rent       100
```

Now i want to join these two tables, the expected result is;

```
Month-----Type-------spent-----Previous Spent
Feb 12  Shopping   100      100
Feb 12  Food       200      100
Feb 12  Fuel       0        100
Feb 12  Rent       0        100
Jan 12  Shopping   456      100
Jan 12  Food       452      100
Jan 12  Fuel       120      100
Jan 12  Rent       900      100
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the "previous expense" table. Is `type` its primary key? (So, for example, that table will only have one `Shopping` record?)

Comment: By the way, you've asked several questions here before, and for most of them, you haven't accepted any answer. If you've found answers helpful, then you should accept them; and if you haven't, then you should re-examine your questions and see if you can figure out why they're not eliciting useful answers. Maybe your questions don't contain enough information about your problems?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select m.month,
       p.type,
       coalesce(c.spent,0) spent,
       p.spent previous_spent
from (select distinct month from current_expense) m
cross join previous_expense p
left join current_expense c 
       on m.month = c.month and p.type = c.type
```

Answer (score 0):

Common Oracle syntax

Select a.*, b.spent 'previous Sent'
from current_expense a, previous_expense b
where a.type = b.type

or the same thing in standard

Select a.*, b.spent 'previous Sent'
from current_expense as a
inner join previous_expense as b on a.type = b.type

Answer (score 0):

I tend to write in SQL92 (more SQLness and less Oracle-ness)
Here is my answer:

```
select
    z.month        as month          ,
    z.type         as type           ,
    nvl(c.spent,0) as spent          ,
    nvl(p.spent,0) as previous_spent
from
    (select 
       x.month as month ,
       y.type  as type
     from
        (select distinct month
         from current_expense) x
         cross join 
           (select distinct type 
            from current_expense) y) z
    left outer join current_expense c
    on z.month = c.month and
       z.type  = z.type
    left outer join previous_expense p
    on z.type = p.type;
```